# A shared object linked to another shared object

Tags: c

i have some problems to understand how the following code works.
I have three files

**Shared.c**

```
#include "shared.h"

void foo1 (void) {
    printf("Test2");
}

void foo2 (void) {
    printf ("Test1");
}
```

**Shared.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void foo2 (void);
extern void foo1 (void);
```

**Shared2.c**

```
//#include "shared.h"
#include "shared2.h"


void shared2 (void){
    foo2();
}
```

**Shared2.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "shared.h"

extern void shared2 (void);
```

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "shared2.h"


int main (void){
    foo2();
}
```

I want to create a binary Test that links shared2.so which depends on shared.so
The above code does not work with the following commands

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC -o shared.o shared.c 
gcc -shared -o libshared.so shared.o -lc
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC -o shared2.o shared2.c
gcc -shared -o libshared2.so shared2.o -lc
```

due to this error

```
shared2.c: In function ‘shared2’:
shared2.c:7:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘foo2’; did you mean ‘feof’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  foo2();
  ^~~~
  feof
```

But the above code works if i remove the comments in Shared2.c and I comment the same line in Shared2.h.

1. Why this error?

If i remove the error and I try to compile test.c

```
gcc -L/MyPath/ -Wall test.c -o test -lshared2 -lshared
```

The compilation works only if i include libshared.so too.

2. But libshared.so is not already included in libshared2.so?

**EDIT**

With your suggestions i've changed the files in this way

**Shared.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "shared.h"


void foo1 (void) {
    printf("Test1");
}

void foo2 (void) {
    printf ("Test2");
}
```

**Shared.h**

```
extern void foo1 (void);
extern void foo2 (void);
```

**Shared2.c**

```
#include "shared.h"
#include "shared2.h"


void shared2 (void){
    foo2();
}
```

**Shared2.h**

```
extern void shared2 (void);
```

And using the following commands

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC -o shared.o shared.c 
gcc -shared -o libshared.so shared.o -lc
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC -o shared2.o shared2.c
gcc -shared -o libshared2.so shared2.o -lc
```

The code is compiled without errors. 
Instead if i make the following changes in **Shared2.c** and **Shared2.h**

**Shared2.c**

```
#include "shared2.h"

void shared2 (void){
        foo2();
    }
```

**Shared2.h**

```
#include "shared.h"

extern void shared2 (void);
```

I obtain an error and i don't understand why

```
shared2.c: In function ‘shared2’:
shared2.c:7:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘foo2’; did you mean ‘feof’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  foo2();
  ^~~~
  feof
```

the prepocessor output (after the substitution of `#include "shared.h"`) should be the same in both cases or not? Why?

Moving on in my tests, after the compilation of `libshared.so` and `libshared2.so`, i've modified my **test.c**

**test.c**

```
#include "shared2.h"


int main (void){
    shared2();
}
```

and if i try to compile with the followng command

```
gcc -L/MyPath/ -Wall -Werror test.c -o test -lshared2
```

I obtain an undefined reference error because gcc is not able to find `foo2()` called in **Shared2.c**. Why this error? Why it needs the reference if i'm using a shared object?

Comment: Note that neither `shared.h` nor `shared2.h` should include `<stdio.h>` because the function declarations do not depend on any of the types defined in `<stdio.h>`.   Further, it is not clear that `shared2.h` should include `shared.h`.  If people cannot call `shared2()` without having one or both of `foo1()` and `foo2()` in scope, then it is reasonable to nest the includes.  If people can call `shared2()` without knowing or caring about either `foo1()` or `foo2()`, then don't nest the includes.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove this error by including "shared.h" into "shared2.c".
2. libshared2.so doesn't include definition of `foo2` function that you are using in your "test" program, that's why you need to add libshared.so at the compile time.

Your "test" program is not actually using "libshared2.so", only `foo2` from "libshared.so". You don't need `-lshared2` here.

Comment: 1. What i've done: i've included "shared.h" into "shared2.c" and it works. I don't know why it does not work if i try to compile the code posted above

Comment: 2. You're right but the libshared.so is linked by libshared2.so: why shall i  write `-lshared` during `test.c` file compilation?

Comment: 1. That's because you're using `foo2` in "shared2.c" but you didn't declare it anywhere. "shared.h" contains that declaration. 2. I didn't read the question correctly - I'll update answer.